# Card.IO on Android with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, card.io

I've been using Card.IO for a while. Recently I switched my build system to Gradle and I noticed the scanner does not work anymore. Instead of the camera popping up, I get a manual entry form instead. I assume this has something to do with the .so files not being included in the build, but I have no idea how to fix this.

I've tried some things in the build.gradle file, such as including '*.so' explicitly and including the subdirectories. But nothing seems to get the scanner back to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gradle Android plugin supports this now, starting version 0.7.2. All you need to do is put the native libraries in src/main/jniLibs

Sources: https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK/issues/9 and http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system

Answer (score 2):

Gradle doesn't yet fully support NDK and hence the *.so files need to be places in the following structure which is different:

```
lib/
 .. armeabi/    armeabi-v7a/    mips/       x86/
```

you can than put it inside of the native-libs.jar, and include that jar with card.io.jar so it ends up in .aar/libs folder.

Hope it helps.

Comment: A more detailed explanation can be found here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/adt-dev/nQobKd2Gl_8