# Android Studio, Gradle and Card.IO

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, crashlytics, card.io

I am not sure how to get my project to build Card.IO with Gradle. My gradle file looks as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "applicationId"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
}
```

My local.properties are as follows:

```
sdk.dir=/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk
ndk.dir=/Applications/Android Studio.app/android-ndk-r10b
```

And my Project structure is as follows:

[image: Quintin Card.IO Project structure]

Now according to Card.IO (https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-SDK) all I need to do is copy the files into the correct directory, but this is not working.

I have also looked at the following posts:
[Card.IO on Android with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688783/card-io-on-android-with-gradle)
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/issues/26 - this suggests some extra gradle methods but does no work

When I do this to my Gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "appId"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
            jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src-gen/main/java']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        x86 {
            versionCode Integer.parseInt("6" + defaultConfig.versionCode)
            ndk {
                abiFilter "x86"
            }
        }
        mips {
            versionCode Integer.parseInt("4" + defaultConfig.versionCode)
            ndk {
                abiFilter "mips"
            }
        }
        armv7 {
            versionCode Integer.parseInt("2" + defaultConfig.versionCode)
            ndk {
                abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
            }
        }
        arm {
            versionCode Integer.parseInt("1" + defaultConfig.versionCode)
            ndk {
                abiFilter "armeabi"
            }
        }
        fat
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
}
```

Then Card.IO works, but I get the error: Crashlytics couldn't find the res folder specified in sourceSets.main.res, please make one. It picked: src/main/res.

I am very sure my problem is just a misunderstanding on Gradle - I am new to it. But there are no up to date complete answers that I can look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere along the line I managed to delete my Res folder using some gradle settings. Now when I put the gradle file back and the res files back it all compiles fine. Weird.

Thank goodness for Android Studio's view local history or I would have been set back a couple of days!

Comment: Glad you figured it out :) Thanks for the detailed question.